# how can I find the limit-pointwise convergence

Tags: analysis

Let $f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0, & x<\frac{1}{n+1} \text{ or } \frac{1}{n}<x\\ 
 \sin^2(\frac{\pi}{x}),&\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n} 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Show that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to a continuous $f$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
Which is this $f$? Is the convergence also uniform?

How can I find to which function $f_n$ converges,when $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your function is $0$ at $0$, and your sequence of functions is equal to zero everywhere except on a set $1/{n+1} \leq x \leq 1/n$ which becomes arbitrarily small. So for any non-zero $z \in {\mathbb R}$, what is the value of $f_n(z)$ if $n >  1/z$? So then what is $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(z)$? As for uniform convergence, find the maximum value of each $f_n$ and compare this to the maximum value of the limit function $f$.

Comment: Could you explain me further how I can find the function at which $f$ converges pointwise?

Comment: @evinda $f$ is the zero function, because $f_n(z) = 0$ for all $n > 1/z$.

Comment: But what happens, if $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}$ ?